# Liquibase checksum validation error without any changes

Tags: maven, liquibase, changeset

Maven fires liquibase validation fail even no changes was made in changeset.

My database is oracle.

Situation:

1. In DB changelog table was record for changeset `<changeSet id="1" author="me" dbms="oracle">`;
2. Then by mistake i added another changeset `<changeSet id="1" author="me" dbms="hsqldb">`
3. Reruned liquibase scripts Maven fired checksum validation error.
4. Then i changed hsqldb changeSet to `<changeSet id="2" author="me" dbms="hsqldb">`
5. Maven still firing checksum validation error.
6. Then i changed first changeSet checksum in DB manually to current checkSum and scripts runned successfully.

Everything looks nice ,but when i redeploy whole application and run liquibase scripts checksum of first changeSet is still like before 6 step.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you're confident that your scripts correctly reflect what *should* be in the database, run the [**liquibase:clearCheckSums**](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_clearchecksums.html) maven goal, which will clean it all up.

Comment: [ERROR] Could not find goal 'clearCheckSums' in plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-plugin:1.9.6 :-(

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen Looking at the link below it seems that the plugin version you're using is quite old - there's probably a newer version under a different name?  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.liquibase%22%20AND%20a%3A%22liquibase-plugin%22

Comment: For gradle it's `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums`

Comment: mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums   ##execute in your project folder

Comment: I tried this and indeed it will successfully run the LB script but it doesn't reflect my changes on database. What I did was delete the problematic databasechangelog.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "scripts correctly reflect what should be in the database", and nor am I sure I understand what the `liquibase:clearCheckSums` maven goal actually does. Will it delete any data? If I had 2 change sets, and the second one is bugged, what happens to the database when I run that command?

Comment: @payne according to https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/maintenance/clear-checksums.html: 

clear-checksums clears all checksums and nullifies the MD5SUM column of the DATABASECHANGELOG table so they will be re-computed on the next database update.

Comment: Also running a query for your Oracle db like:

`UPDATE your_table_name.DATABASECHANGELOG
SET MD5SUM = NULL;` 

Will do the job

Answer (score 20):

Everyone here is talking about how to fix this, but let me share a typical scenario where it may occur for you.

> **SHORT ANSWER : Change in line-separator due to one reason or another can cause checksum validation error and won't be visible in code
>   changes.**

Why did it occur for me? Please read below..

Suppose you have a tomcat server, and multiple people are involved in WAR deployment from time to time. Everyone uses INTELLIJ IDEA on LINUX but one of the team member switches to WINDOWS for some reason. 
Now, when the WINDOWS PERSON would create WAR, he may not notice that default line-separator selection in INTELLIJ IDEA for WINDOWS is CRLF but all previous builds built from LINUX machine which uses LF line-separator.

Change in line-separator affects all text files, which includes SQL files too. So you may have used following just like my team in your liquibase script

```
changeSet(author: "aditya", id: "1335831637231-1") {
    sqlFile( path: "liquibase/quartz_oracle_tables.sql", "stripComments": true)
}
```

and the checksum of file would not match the one already stored in database throwing checksum validation error.

Comment: Would be worth adding this as a separate question - the original question was "I change my files, then Liquibase fails, why?" whereas this is "I didn't change my files, but Liquibase *still* fails, why???!"

Comment: I am not sure if we are allowed to that, but yes it can help people better in the same scenario I faced.

Comment: This answer was helpful from my perspective. Note, it comes up as first result for  searching "liquidbase validation failed checksum"

Comment: It occurs when you are modifying the already executed changeset.

Answer (score 19):

In my case I forgot that *Liquibase* writes all changelogs to database table.

Go to *DATABASECHANGELOG* table and remove manually your changelogs.

Answer (score 15):

Liquibase reads `databasechangelog` table to validate recent changes.
So identify the `databasechangelog` id which is causing the problem and delete, as shown below:

```
select * from myschema.DATABASECHANGELOG;

Delete from myschema.DATABASECHANGELOG where ID='prob_id';
```

[Deleting a bad changelog in Liquibase](https://bastide.org/2017/11/24/deleting-a-bad-changelog-in-liquibase/)

Comment: This really saved the day for me!

Comment: To force validation of your test instance where the changelog failed for a non-idempotent change:

update databasechangelog set md5sum = 'checksum_from_error_message' where id = 'MyChangeID;

Comment: works flawlessly @Nandan

Answer (score 6):

As I struggle with this one I want to make it easier for people with this same issue:

1. Important!, liquibase has a changlog.xml file
2. On the maven pom.xml place the following properties.

```html
<project ...>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>*****</version>
      <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/mychangelogfile.xml</changeLogFile>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//X.X.X.X:PORT/XE</url>
        <username>yourusername</username>
        <password>password</password>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>clearCheckSums</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</project>
```

**** version the one I used 3.2.0
in url replace with proper IPADDRESS and PORT.

Finally you run `mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

[The liquibase documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changelog-formats.html) has a 2nd option now

```
The <validCheckSum> attribute

The second option is to add a <validCheckSum> element to the changeset. The text contents of the element should contain the old checksum from the error message.
```

Assuming you rarely have to change historic changelog XML files, then you rarely have error messages. If you get an error message then add a tag with the old checksum acknowledging it's fine.

Example:

```
    <changeSet id="example" author="former-author" runOnChange="false">
       <validCheckSum>8:869....4e3</validCheckSum>
       <addColumn tableName="ye_olde_db_table">
          <!-- fix some old typo or incompatibility, etc -->
       </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

Comment: If nothing changed, this should be the accepted answer, since it keeps the solution in the liquibase side. Otherwise I would have to run liquibase:clearCheckSums pointing to my remote databases on each k8s environment (dev, stage, prod, etc), for example, which is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Configure liquibase's database link information in the maven plugin.

like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <changeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hos_gateway</url>
    <username>root</username>
    <password>root</password>
    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.hos.physician.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <logging>debug</logging>
    <contexts>!test</contexts>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changeset id should not repeat. Give a new changeset id and try, it should work.

```
<changeSet id=
```

Comment: bad bad practice

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changelog.yml file had incorrect id.

databaseChangeLog:

- changeSet:
  id: 1.0.xx