# Liquibase - disable checksum?

Tags: liquibase

How can I disable checksum validation in Liquibase?

It looks like Liquibase does not provide such feature. Would it be hard to modify Liquibase to achieve that? Your opinion, please.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995747/liquibase-checksum-validation-error-without-any-changes

Comment: thank you, Marvin. that solution would work, but we integrate Liquibase in our Spring applications. what we want to do is ignore the checksums when the app is deployed on a server. at that time, there is no Maven.

Comment: Why would you want to disable checksums? They're a very important feature in liquibase designed to protect against applying a changeset more than once to a database instance. Yes, the clearCheckSums command is provided but this is a feature designed to recover from abnormal behaviour, for example when someone changes a changeset.... See what I mean? normally a changeset should not be changed. That is an example of how the use of checksums protects your production database.

Comment: Mark, I understand the purpose of checksums and their importance. Still we want to disable them for our projects. That's what's best for us.

Comment: Is this about deployment or validation at startup? Some apps are doing an initial validation on database before starting.

Comment: @anton1980 you have to accept chris's answer

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try adding `validCheckSum` with the literal `ANY` to the top of your `changeSet`, like this:

```
<changeSet>
    <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
    <!-- the rest of your changeSet here -->
</changeSet>
```

Comment: It must be the literal ANY

Comment: this works for Liquibase 3, but not Liquibase 2. we asked this question for Liquibase 2 and ended up modifying its code to achieve similar results.

Comment: Note that during development it might be tempting to use `ANY` but you are asking for trouble in the future it gets left in. It is a good idea to use the actual checksum instead of `ANY`.

Comment: @span we use it at my company for our csv loads so we don't have to add a new file for each update to a large list of values.  Without this, adding a value to a long csv would fail the checksum making re-use not an option.

In almost all cases that I can think of except the one I mentioned, I agree with you that it is bad to use ANY as a checksum.

Comment: If you use .groovy files for liquibase, you can write : validCheckSum('ANY')