# Liquibase : checksum changed and I don't know why

Tags: liquibase

I am having trouble with liquibase.
When I run my J2EE application, liquibase tells me :

```
liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160324155624_added_entity_Consultant.xml::20160324155624::jhipster is now: 7:30bd20fc51a6e6711ba189760c980415
```

I don't remember having changed the Consultant entity. So I don't understand why I am having this error.

If someone can tell in which case this type of error occurs... Because I don't really understand its meaning.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you move the changelog files into a different dir? I think the path is part of the checksum. Or maybe you just execute liquibase from a different Computer where the files are stored in a different path?

Comment: I didnt' change anything. If I change the content of the file, can this change create that kind of issue?

Comment: Yes it can. Once the change was run on your database you're not supposed to change it anymore.

Comment: You can clear the checksums if you want to and if you're confident. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10000393/332248)

Answer (score 0):

If your change set loads a file using the `<loadData file=someFile.csv />` tag then liquibase will also include that file's contents in the checksum calculation. So any change to `someFile.csv` will change the checksum of your changeset, even though your changeset hasn't changed.